# Ruby - Loop IF x times and change condition

Tags: ruby

I would like to loop 20 times over an if statement, but each time it's run, some things must change.

Example:

```
    input = [0,0,0,44,754,22,0,632,2,22,0,2,nil,2,24,nil,666,90909,2,4,6,7,2,7,3,2,2,7,1,8,6,3,2,19,5,46]

Statement = "Statement THIS"

if
input[1] != nil &&
    input[2] == 0
  Statement.sub! "THIS", "WHERE #{input[8]} #{input[9]} THIS"
else
end

puts Statement #Statement WHERE 2 22 THIS

if
input[5] != nil &&
    input[6] == 0
  Statement.sub! "THIS", "AND #{input[12]} #{input[13]} THIS"
else
end

puts Statement #Statement WHERE 2 22 AND  2 THIS

if
input[9] != nil &&
    input[10] == 0
  Statement.sub! "THIS", "AND #{input[16]} #{input[17]} THIS"
else
end

puts Statement #Statement WHERE 2 22 AND  2 AND 666 90909 THIS
```

In the second IF statement the following things have changed:

1. Each key has increased by 4 (1,2,8,9 became 5,6,12,13)
2. The word WHERE has changed to AND

I would like this behaviour to repeat another 18 times, so the third IF statement has:

1. Each key has increased by 4 (5,6,12,13 became 9,10,16,17)
2. The word HELLO has changed to GOODBYE (however this rule is now redundant, since the second IF statement took care of it).

Comment: so what is the problem? cannot you make `if elsif`?

Comment: I can, but I have more than 30 if-statements and each would need this behaviour (20 loops). The result would be extremely lengthy and I'm wondering if some sort of loop is possible with this behaviour.

Comment: Seems like I do not understand. What is initial data?

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the question code. It's working as I need, but I want to execute it 18 more with the key numbers changed in each IF. I can write the code 18 more times, or perhaps there is a faster method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = [
  0,0,0,44,754,22,0,632,2,22,0,2,
  nil,2,24,nil,666,90909,2,4,6,7,
  2,7,3,2,2,7,1,8,6,3,2,19,5,46
]

(1..Float::INFINITY).step(4) do |i|
  i = i.to_i # is float here
  break Statement if i >= input.size
  next if input[i].nil? || !input[i+1].zero?

  keyword = Statement =~ /WHERE/ ? 'AND' : 'WHERE'
  Statement.sub! "THIS", "#{keyword} #{input[i+7]} #{input[i+8]} THIS"
end
#⇒ "Statement WHERE 2 22 AND  2 AND 666 90909 THIS"
```

Comment: Perfect and nice solution with the break, instead of 20x loop, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To loop 20 times you can use the *times* method.

```
arr_index = 1

20.times do
  if arr_index < 1
    operator = "WHERE"
  else
    operator = "AND"
  end


  if input[arr_index] != nil && input[arr_index + 1] == 0
    Statement.sub! "THIS", "#{operator} #{input[arr_index + 7]} #{input[arr_index + 8]} THIS"
  end

  arr_index += 4
end
```

Another option would be to change the contents of your *input* array or create another data structure (e.g., hash, array, array of hashes, hash of arrays) with the exact values you need for the loop. Thus, eliminating the need to increment the index by 4 at each iteration.

Also, unless *Stamement* is a class or a constant, convention dictates its name should be lower case (e.g., statement).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it came in handy too.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 20

"STATEMENT WHERE %s THEN" % (1..1+4*(n-1)).step(4).with_object([]) { |i,a|
  a << "#{ input[i+7] } #{ input[i+8] }" unless input[i].nil? || input[i+1] != 0 }.
  join(" AND ") 
  #=> "Statement WHERE 2 22 AND  2 AND 666 90909 THEN"
```